# is there a way to know the specific selected option in a tk.menu without referencing its content (just the status)?

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, menu, selected

Imagine a menubutton that contains two submenus (Tree1 and Tree2). Each submenu contains two options: "Pear" and "Apple". Is there a way to know from which Tree (submenu) a "Pear" came from after someone else picked it?

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def F_WhatsTheTree(event):
    # This should tell me the tree from which the selected fruit comes
    return

# I create a menubutton with a menu inside
menubutton = tk.Menubutton(root, text="Menu")
menubutton.menu = tk.Menu(menubutton, tearoff=0)
menubutton["menu"] = menubutton.menu

# then I create two submenus
menubutton.menu.submenu1 = tk.Menu(menubutton.menu, tearoff=0)
menubutton.menu.submenu2 = tk.Menu(menubutton.menu, tearoff=0)

# add some cascades to them
menubutton.menu.add_cascade(label="Tree1", menu=menubutton.menu.submenu1)
menubutton.menu.add_cascade(label="Tree2", menu=menubutton.menu.submenu2)

# then some fruits
menubutton.menu.submenu1.add_radiobutton(label="Pear")
menubutton.menu.submenu1.add_radiobutton(label="Apple")
menubutton.menu.submenu2.add_radiobutton(label="Pear")
menubutton.menu.submenu2.add_radiobutton(label="Apple")

# I pack the whole thing
menubutton.pack()

root.bind("<Button-3>", F_WhatsTheTree)

root.mainloop()
```

I have tried something like this:

```py
def F_WhatsTheTree(event):
    for i in range(len(menubutton.menu.winfo_children())):
        Submenu = menubutton.menu.winfo_children()[i]
        for j in range(Submenu.index("end")+1):
            if Submenu.index(j) == Submenu.index("active"):
                #I have also tried:
                #Submenu.index(tk.ACTIVE)
                #Submenu.index(tk.CURRENT)
                print("The damn tree is: "+Submenu)
```

...but I don't know how to reference the "selected" option of a menu or the "selected" status of a radiobutton.

I've been reading the documentation of both the menu and the radiobutton to try find a way to do this, but I got nothing (obviously).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend giving each radiobutton a distinct value.

For example:

```
...submenu1.add_radiobutton(label="Pear" value="submenu1.pear")
...submenu1.add_radiobutton(label="Apple", value="submenu1.apple")
...menu.submenu2.add_radiobutton(label="Pear", value="submenu2.pear")
...menu.submenu2.add_radiobutton(label="Apple", value="submenu2.apple")
```

Then, in the code that uses the value you can strip off everything before the period to know which menu it came from.

Comment: Thank you, Bryan. But I need to avoid any solution that references the specific contents of the radiobuttons. I'd like to know how, by the way the code is right now, the program remembers the Pear I clicked on. Because whenever I reopen the menu, the Pear marked as selected remains the same (the menu knows the tree that contains the selected Pear without any other additional data). He knows. He knows!

Comment: Oh, wait a second. He actually doesn't know. The program actually marks the Pears of both trees. What a stupid program I've written. Thanks again, Brian. I'll mark your answer as the good one because there's no other way, apparently.